# Unexpected T_WHILE error

Tags: php, html, mysql

Can anybody point out what I am doing wrong in my code below? I'm getting an "UNEXPECTED T_WHILE" error.

```
echo '
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Events</td>
        <td>Category</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>', while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) { $title = $row['eventTitle']; echo $title; }, '</td>
        <td>', while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) { $category = $row['eventTitle']; echo $category; }, '</td>
    </tr>
</table> ';
```

Comment: You just can't place a while in the middle of an echo statement.

Comment: Thanks John for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

First off, close your PHP tags.

```
?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Events</td>
        <td>Category</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) {
                    $title = $row['eventTitle'];
                    echo $title;
                }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) {
                    $category = $row['eventTitle'];
                    echo $category;
                }
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is as close as it gets to solve my problems! :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you need anything else I'm usually around. Please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP -**

```
$array = array();

$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) 
{ 
    $array[$i]['title'] = $row['eventTitle'];
    $array[$i]['category'] = $row['eventCategory'];
    $i++;      
}
```

**HTML -**

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Events</td>
    <td>Category</td>
</tr>

<?php
   foreach($array as $arr)
   {
?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $arr['event']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $arr['category']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
    }
?>
```